# If I delete groups, are users in those groups deleted?

Tags: group, useradd

I use ubuntu 14.04 and made 120 users. 115 users are in "student" and 5 users are in "assistant".

If I delete groups, then are users in those groups deleted too?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You just end up with users whose login group doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 0):

You may not remove the primary group of any existing user. You must remove the user before you remove the group. (see gropudel documentation)

Comment: The OP didn't say with what tool the group would be deleted.  Userdel will simply refuse to remove the group, but you can still delete the group (e.g., manually), and nothing will happen to the users.

Answer (score 0):

No, as long as the user has a primary group which is different to "student" or "assistant" then they can be deleted easily however if these groups are the users primary groups then you will not be able to delete them without giving the users a new primary group.